# Google Cloud Data Fusion is not producing CSV output in GCS Bucket

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, etl, google-cloud-data-fusion

I have a pipeline that recursively reads many JSON files from a Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket, then parses each file into a record. Each record then goes through a "Python Transform" plugin for further processing (adding new fields and values), and finally it should be saved in a different GCS bucket (the sink).

All my attempts at playing with the parameters of the GCS sink, and adding a "Wrangler" transform before it, and/or adding a "CSV Formatter" transform before the "Wrangler" transform, have not helped produce a CSV file. The preview output is always correct, but when deployed, the output is not.

The file produced in my chosen path is always a file name I did not choose and it is always a file type "application/octet-stream".

[The first attempt (full pipeline)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfoQ7.png)

[The second type of attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggs37.png)

[The third type of attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKGP3.png)

[This is the GCS properties window, and nothing in it is different between the above attempts except for the schema.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3FQ0.png)

This is the output, every time: [Deployed pipeline output as octet-stream instead of CSV, and with file name I did not choose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGn9I.png)

How can I choose the file name, and what am I doing wrong with producing the output that it does not come out as a CSV in the GCS bucket?

Comment: I hope the output file (part-r-00000) has cvs formatted data but only desired file name and ".csv" extension is missing.

As a workaround, You may write the output of dataframe (cvs data) in python transformation. for example below are few lines  spark scale code 

val file_fullpathname = "${pathnamecsv}"
df.write.format("csv").save(file_fullpathname)

Comment: I believe the output file does have a csv format. I appreciate but also don't understand your suggestion @narendra. 1) I can enter ${pathnamecsv} as a runtime argument, if that's what you mean, but I don't know where to enter in the spark code `val file_fullpathname = "${pathnamecsv}"`. 2) The python transform tool works on a single record at a time and emits that record, so I also don't know where `df.write.format("csv").save(file_fullpathname)` would go. The Python transform function has the form `def transform(record, emitter, context)`

Comment: I am not sure what python transform does. I am sharing a work around i used. You may give a try to this then see if this fit in your scenarios : GCS source -> Wrangler -> Spark  -> trash . Wrangler to parse the source file as  csv and then return a data frame to Spark plugin, in spark plugin i have put the above code to write a csv file using Scala code. Btw have you tried writing file inside the Python transform function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing this, after considering the comments and ideas proposed (@narendra, @Edwin, @Rally) I experimented with the different plugins and this is how I settled on a solution:

I used the Spark Sink plugin, and the FileDelete plugin, which can be placed after a sink.

[image]

The code for the Spark Sink is simple:

```
def sink(df: DataFrame, context: SparkExecutionPluginContext) : Unit = {
  val fillerVar = "${fillerVar}"
  val fullpath = "gs://somebucket/output/leader_board/"
  df.coalesce(1)
    .write.format("csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("encoding", "UTF-8")
    .mode("append")
    .save(fullpath)

}
```

The output includes not only a CSV file, but also an empty "_SUCCESS" file. This is deleted using the FileDelete plugin:

[image]

I recognized that I (right now) cannot find a simple way to change the output file name (whether one file or multiple files merged) through the plugins. And since I don't know Scala/Java well enough, I couldn't figure it out that way either.

For my purposes, I'm using Google Data Fusion to produce output to use with Google Data Studio. Data Studio can take as a data source not just individual files, but you can point it to a GCS bucket path and it will read all the files therein. Therefore it doesn't bother me anymore that I can't control the filename ("part-00000-[random]).

Answer (score 0):

I replicated this as well and I also cannot choose the name and the type of the file I want. Since there is no content type option to choose from the sink, the file is outputted as a default file which is part-r-00000 with a file type of application/octet-stream.

> If the Content-Type is not specified by the uploader and cannot be
> determined, it is set to application/octet-stream. [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata#content-type)

I have created a feature request for this which you can also track the progress.

https://issuetracker.google.com/171366470

I agree with @narendra's suggested workaround to add the filenames via Spark Scala code.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. I'm going to follow and comment on the feature request because the path suffix also looks broken. Whenever I delete the path suffix, which is optional, it magically returns. Also I will likely edit my question up there to add my further failed attempts, including what was suggested in Spark

Answer (score 0):

Currently the GCS sink plugin do not support adding a name to the files written, since the files being written to the sink can be split into multiple parts. We can add a feature request to have a GCS action that you can run after the sink to concat the files into one and have specify names there.

Comment: Thank you, I agree, we should request such a feature.